# No component for supporting the service was found error

Tags: wcf, installation, castle-windsor

We have setup a .net application developed with .net framework 4.0 using MVC framework and WCF service on a Windows 2003, 32-bit server containing IIS 6 successfully.

However, when the same application is set up on a Win 2008 R2, 64-bit server, we get the following error when the application is accessing the WCF service:

No component for supporting the service was found 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service  was found

We have set the flag for Enable 32-bit apps in "Application Pool" to true on the 64-bit server.

Comment: please post the full exception stack trace and message

Comment: I have the same issue with you, have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this is related to WCF itself. `ComponentNotFound` is thrown by Windsor Castle IoC container and it means that something is wrong with its configuration. So when IoC tries to resolve the type of service it doesn't find related configuration.